# Explaining the divergence of $\int_{-\infty}^{0}\frac{1}{3-4x}\text{d}x$

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

This is mostly to see if my solution is correct. I would like to show that 
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{0}\dfrac{1}{3-4x}\text{ d}x$$
is a divergent integral.

Notice
$$\begin{align}
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{0}\dfrac{1}{3-4x}\text{ d}x = \lim\limits_{t\to -\infty}\int\limits_{t}^{0}\dfrac{1}{3-4x}\text{ d}x &= \lim\limits_{t \to -\infty}\int\limits_{t}^{0}(3-4x)^{-1}\text{ d}x \\
&= -\dfrac{1}{4}\lim\limits_{t \to -\infty}\int\limits_{3-4t}^{3}u^{-1}\text{ d}u \\
&= -\dfrac{1}{4}\lim\limits_{t\to -\infty}\left[\ln(3)-\ln(3-4t)\right] \to \infty\text{.}
\end{align}$$
Hence the integral diverges.

Comment: Your method works and it's fine. Another way could be using the fact that $\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{3-4x}dx=\frac{1}{4}ln|3-4x|+C$ and you get the answer immediately.

Comment: According to my old calc. II professor, the fact that it even looks like $\frac{1}{x}$ means it's divergent. Of course, the limits of integration matter but it is a divergent function.